# Styling of ListBoxItem Not Working

Tags: c#, wpf, listboxitem

I'm attempting to style the ListBoxItems within my listbox but the content of the ListBoxItem does not display and any change in colours are not apparent. The only thing working is the "border bottom" that I've applied to the bottom of each list item.

```
<Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border BorderBrush="#FF66AFDE" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" />
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: You've just created `ControlTemplate` for `ContentControl` without `ContentPresenter` within your `Border`

Comment: Even with ContentPresenter in there, no text is displayed. Same for ItemsPresenter.

Comment: And if remove your `Template` and `OverridesDefaultStyle` and use default one do you see some content?

Comment: *face into desk* yes I do now. But how would I use controltemplate.triggers without the template? E.g. IsFocused

Comment: try adding `TargetType` like so `<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">`

Comment: That causes the listboxitem to disappear completely.

Comment: I've just tried your example with `ContentPresenter` and `TargetType` and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
 <Style x:Key="ListItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="30" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                    <Border BorderBrush="#FF66AFDE" BorderThickness="0 0 0 1" x:Name="border">
                        <ContentPresenter/>
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

I hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Use a panel/container/decorator in the *ListBoxItem* control template to set the background color. (It seems that the logic for setting the selection background color will interfere with attempts to control its background color.)

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
    <Border
        Name="PART_Border"
        Focusable="true"
        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
        BorderBrush="#FF66AFDE"
        BorderThickness="0 0 0 1"
    >
        <ContentPresenter />
    </Border>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
            <Setter
                Property="Background"
                Value="Red"
                TargetName="PART_Border"
            />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Also note, that `Border.Focusable` is by default **false**. If setting it to *true* doesn't work (i admit, i haven't tested), use a different container control instead of Border.

Also, if the content you will show has any controls receiving focus (such as buttons or text fields), the trigger might not work as expected, because the Border might **not** have the focus when a control of the content has the focus. Also, tabbing from control to control might exhibit unexpected behaviour. If you have to deal with such a situation, try to handle the trigger in an ItemTemplate instead.

Regarding the `ContentPresenter` not showing anything: Depending on the type of the elements in the ItemsSource, you might need to define a *ListBox.ItemTemplate* (or *ListBox.ItemTemplateSelector*), otherwise *ContentPresenter* might not know what to display.